# Receiver (<ViewController:>) has no segue with identifier 'showAlerting''

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue, viewdidappear

The segue runs but the app crashes with the above error. Why do I get this `no segue with identifier` message? I defined the segue Identifier.

[image]

Here is the viewDidAppear method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlerting" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlerting"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Logging showAlerting");
    }
}
```

I got these log messages

```
2015-03-28 20:04:33.025 xxxx[3684:741007] Logging showAlerting
2015-03-28 20:04:33.046 xxxx[3684:741007] xxxxxxxx,,
2015-03-28 20:04:33.111 xxxx[3684:741007]  lat: xxx
2015-03-28 20:04:33.112 xxxx[3684:741007]  lon: xxx
2015-03-28 20:04:33.798 xxxx[3684:741007] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ViewController: 0x17d38930>) has no segue with identifier 'showAlerting''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c1a15a7 0x39d87c77 0x2f9830df 0xebde7 0x2f6bb37b 0x2f6bb837 0x2f9701bb 0x2fd00e89 0x2f9726ff 0x2f7b5baf 0x2f7b5a4f 0x2f7b5525 0x2f6d9201 0x2f6d9117 0x2f0d363b 0x276187 0x279e9d 0x2c167891 0x2c165fb1 0x2c0b2b51 0x2c0b2963 0x335f11a9 0x2f704c91 0xea5f5 0x3a330aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one instance of ViewController?

Comment: I don't know, I got a `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.xib` does that make two ViewController instances?

Comment: What is the class of the controller you're segueing to? Check its class in the storyboard.

Comment: both source and destination are class `ViewController`

Comment: Ok, that's your problem then, because the second one doesn't have a segue attached to it. You should change the class of that controller.

Comment: It works after I switched viewcontroller to UIViewcontroller

Comment: @rdelmar I'll mark it as solution if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two instances of the same class in the storyboard; one with the segue, and one without. The controller that's being segued to needs to be a different class than the one you're segueing from.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller is not completely loaded when you are trying to access its segue. So call super and complete the load process and then call prepareForSegue.

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlerting" sender:self];
    }
```

Comment: I got the same error with `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. He should call super, but the view is fully loaded by the time viewDidAppear is called.