# Initiating segue from error: "Receiver has no segue with identifier"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to show a new screen via a segue, labeled `toConsoleScreen`.  I keep getting the error:

> Receiver () has
>   no segue with identifier 'toConsoleScreen'

I am 100% sure that my segue is labeled `toConsolescreen`, and the segue is connected in the `Interface Builder`.

The 'rootViewController' hasn't been touched, but I created a new `UIViewController` for the 2nd page called `Console Screen`, with a class of `ConsoleViewController`.

What am I doing wrong? It tells me it can't find the segue `toConsoleScreen` when it's obviously present.

I'm using:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConsoleScreen", sender: self)
```

from within the `ViewController`. I have tried deleting the segue and recreating it (using the 'show' setting), as well as running the Product -> Clean feature.

I should also add that I'm trying to call `performSegue` within a function inside of `ViewController`. This function is called from a separate `Swift` file. I'm somewhat new to Swift, so how can I make this possible?

Here is my current ViewController.Swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var UserNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PasswordField: UITextField!

func successfulLogin(Username: String) {

    // Show next view \\

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConsoleScreen", sender: self)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func loginButton() {

            login(Username: UserNameField.text!, Password: PasswordField.text!)
}



}
```

And my Login.swift file:

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit



func login(Username: String, Password: String) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "web address")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "action=login&username=\(Username)&password=\(Password)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
    }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        if responseString! == "success" {
            print("Good")

            // Send to new page \\


            ViewController().successfulLogin(Username: Username)
    }



        if responseString! == "fail" {

            print("failed")
            // Alert Error \\


        func alertPopup(title: String, message: String) {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  nil))
            }

            // Add to main Queue \\
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
            alertPopup(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Login")
            }
    }


}
task.resume()



}
```

Comment: Are you calling this in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Tried these many many solutions? If so, you should update your question to avoid a duplicate flag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057818/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier-error-message  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241877/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324132/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-showalerting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020866/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier-when-identifier-exists

Comment: Thanks.  I've restated my question.

Comment: You mentioned that this function is called from a seperate Swift file. Is that file a ViewController?

Comment: I apologize.  I have included all of my code now.

Comment: Make sure that the `UIViewController` the segue is being performed from is set in the storyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiver has no segue with identifier error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057818/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier-error-message)

Comment: Brandon, could you elaborate?  How do I 'set' the `UIViewController` in the storyboard?  The segue is attached to the `ViewController` that defaults on screen when you first open the `Main.Storyboard`.

Comment: I've updated with code below, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call the method like this:

```
ViewController().successfulLogin(Username: Username)
```

The above code will init a new instance of ViewController. You should use delegate pattern or completion handler to call the `successfulLogin` method.

Example of using completion handler:

In `ViewController.swift`:

```
@IBAction func loginButton() {
        login(Username: UserNameField.text!, Password: PasswordField.text!) { username in
            self.successfulLogin(Username: username)
        }
    }
```

In `Login.swift`:

```
func login(Username: String, Password: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "web address")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "action=login&username=\(Username)&password=\(Password)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
    }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        if responseString! == "success" {
            print("Good")

            // Send to new page \\


            completion(Username)
    }



        if responseString! == "fail" {

            print("failed")
            // Alert Error \\


        func alertPopup(title: String, message: String) {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  nil))
            }

            // Add to main Queue \\
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation{
            alertPopup(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Login")
            }
    }


}
task.resume()



}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I've been trying to accomplish!  Code worked flawlessly, minus one exception...  I had to add `OperationQueue.main.addOperation` to the `performSegue` call.  I owe you a coffee (or a beer if you prefer that instead...).

Comment: Ok, so back to this again...  Once the next view controller loads (ConsoleViewController), I have a couple of different features on the view.  A "Check In" button, and a "Update Next Date" button.  The result of those buttons will bring up a UIAlertView.  I keep getting the "...view is not in the window hierarchy!" error.  App doesn't crash, but no AlertView shows...  Any insight @chengsam?

Comment: @RyanSady You should open a new question regarding this.